# How to display a list of <v-img> using v-for method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi and good day everyone.
How to display a list of image by using v-for method in Vue js?

If I have a code like this:

```
<v-flex>
        <h4>{{$translate('bz_doc_path')}}</h4>
        <p><a :href="business_doc_path">{{business_doc_path}}</a></p>
        <v-img
        :src="business_doc_path"
        max-width="50%"
        max-height="auto"
        />
</v-flex>
```

data component:

```
<script>
  export default {
         data(){
           return {
           business_doc_path: this.props.business_doc_path
  }
 },
 props:[
    'props'
 ],
 computed:{
 r(){
  return this.props
  },
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the v-for directive on the v-flex component. v-for requires a list or object (iterable) and also a key. See docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for

```
<v-flex v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <h4>{{$translate(item['bz_doc_path'])}}</h4>
        <p><a :href="item['business_doc_path']">{{item['business_doc_path']}}</a></p>
        <v-img
        :src="item['business_doc_path']"
        max-width="50%"
        max-height="auto"
        />
</v-flex>
```